# Dataview web part fails after minor changes

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, xslt, sharepoint-designer, dataviewwebpart

We're working with a sharepoint 2007 site that has a number of dataview webparts showing different views of a document repositry. Each time we make even the most minor change (such as changing the chrome settings or adding a class) to the XSLT or webpart settings the DV webpart refuses to render.

Our XSL is vaild, as is the page the GUID is correct for the list and we are at a loss. We've resorted to editing the CAML files deleting and reimporting them which is obviously very slow. Any thoughts/ideas/help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced this problem at our place too. Often I have found out that it is because of JS errors. Do you notice any errors on the IE? Did you try refershing the page by doing a CTRL+F5? I hope this helps, coz at times it does for me. I dont know the root cause and never cared to look into since it has happened only a few times.

Comment: It was causing me huge problems for about two days, I finished up editing the CAML directly and reimporting the webpart with each change.